# How do I use the pandas split-apply-combine style strategy with scala api in spark?

Tags: pandas, scala, apache-spark, split-apply-combine

I have a scala function which takes a spark dataframe and returns a single value, a double say. The function is complicated, uses aggregations defined in the DataFrame class, calls out to other java libraries and can't be expressed in SQL. It requires the entire contents of the dataframe to do the computation, it can't add a row at a time and build up to a result.

I have a large dataframe which contains a column i would like to use to split the dataframe into small chunks and perform the above calculation on each small chunk. I would then like to return a new dataframe containing one row for each group with two columns, one containing the groupby value and another containing the result.

This would be a relatively straightforward task using PandasUDFs but I cannot work out how i can do this in Scala.

I have tried to repartition the dataframe using the group by column and then call mapPartitions, however the function passed to mapPartitions must have the signature Iterator[Row] -> Iterator[X]. I can take Iterator[Row] and create Seq[Row] or List[Row] easy enough, but it appears to not be possible to create a dataframe from this Seq as the computation is being done on the worker nodes and creating a dataframe can only be done from the driver. It would require a lot of re-engineering to rewrite the original function to take Seq[Row] as it uses some high level aggregation functions from DataFrame (approxQuantile for example).

The crux of the problem seems to be that there is no notion of a "local (/worker only/not distributed) dataframe" in contrast to Pandas where the dataframes are obviously constrained to be local.

Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

*I have a large dataframe which contains a column i would like to use to split the dataframe into small chunks and perform the above calculation on each small chunk.*

Are the values in that column known beforehand? If not, are they collectable at least? Let's say you can collect them, as:

```
val chunkValues: Array[Any] = df.select("chunk")
  .collect()
  .map(r => r.getAs[Any](0))
```

Loop over the values to filter the inputDF several times and do your heavy logic:

```
val chunkDFs: Array[DataFrame] = chunkValues.map(value => {
  val chunkBeforeDF = inputDF.filter(col("chunk") === value)
  val chunkAfterDF = yourLogic(chunkBefore)
})
```

Union them again.